# Detect Windows Version With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Specifically, I am trying to detect Windows XP users as they are not compatible with my software.

Is there a way to detect with at least 70% or higher accuracy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `navigator.appVersion`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533080(v=VS.85).aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.appVersion

I have Windows 7 here and the `navigator.appVersion` returns a string containing "NT 6.1" in these browsers: Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE9 beta.

Only Firefox does not return that info in that string :(

btw, WinXP is "NT 5.1", Vista is "NT 6.0" ...

***Update***

`navigator.userAgent` returns the "NT version" string in all 5 browsers. That means that `userAgent` is the property that is able to tell the Windows version.

Comment: navigator.userAgent should contain this string(NT 5.1) also in Firefox.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Could you test it? Put `javascript:alert(navigator.appVersion)` in the address-bar of Firefox and press ENTER. It could be that my Firefox installation is corrupted somehow (because I'm running 3.6 and 4beta at the same time)

Comment: My Firefox returns for appVersion  `5.0 (Windows; de)` . I'm using 3.6.11 on WinXP. `navigator.userAgent` returns a string containing the needed information **NT 5.1**

Comment: @Šime Vidas: FF3.6.11 on winxp pro sp3: `5.0 (Windows; en-US)`

Comment: Yes, same with me. It seems that `userAgent` is the correct property then

Comment: Tested with Netscape 4.79 , it returns NT 5.0 on winXP ^^

Comment: @Dr.Molle I thought WinXP is NT 5.1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT I guess, we can just search for "NT 5" then

Comment: You're right, Netscape 4.7 is providing wrong information(NT 5.0 is win2000, I never had it). But This test was just a joke, I think we all can live with problems in NN4.7

Comment: Windows 8 is `NT 6.2`, just saying.

Comment: In 2018 this method should be viewed with some scepticism, [`Do not rely on this property to return the correct browser version.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can use the `navigator` host object:

```
var os = navigator.platform
```

See here for more info:
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1100686

Also:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: I tried finding more information and I found this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_platform.asp which is not very well-documented. Is there better documentation out there for navigator.platform? EDIT: Looks like, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform, you cannot detect specific OS versions within Windows

Comment: I haven't been able to find much, but here's something I did find: http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/NavigatorPlatformProperty
EDIT: Firefox/Gecko reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform

Comment: @user396449 You have to search for the MSDN (IE) and MDC (Firefox) articles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534340(v=VS.85).aspx and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.platform

Comment: @Tim & @Šime: Neither of those articles are able to detect specific versions of Windows

Comment: @user394669 Take a look at my answer. With `navigator.appVersion` you are able to detect the Windows version (NT 6.1 for Win7, etc.) in all browsers except Firefox

Comment: [`The specification allows browsers to always return the empty string, so don't rely on this property to get a reliable answer.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.navigator.appVersion.split("NT")[1].split(";")[0].trim()
```

Will return the Windows version.