# Chek Windows Vista using Javascript

Tags: javascript

how can i found Windows Vista Service Pack version using javascript..

Comment: first hit on google for 'checking os with js' ~_~ : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: i know how to fine OS using javascript but problem in found Win Vista

Comment: well, a starting point is typing  `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)` in your address bar and looking at what comes up. Xp comes up with Windows NT 5.1 and win7 comes up with NT 6.1 (I think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Windows Version With JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006420/detect-windows-version-with-javascript)

Comment: Side question: I'm curious why do you want to know the OS in a system that is supposed to be platform independent?

Comment: When client open my website, i need to check Operating system and Service pack version of client machine

Answer (score 0):

By using Javascript try 
alert(navigator.userAgent));

However I am not sure if, it is cross browser. Better way would be to use server side languages.

By using PHP, you can do this.

```
<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>
```

Both, Javascript and PHP outputs something like this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12
```

You can detect the OS using this output as Windows NT 6.1 is `Windows 7`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN article on user-agent strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can assume that a user-agent platform token containing the string "Windows NT 6.0" indicates that the client machine is running Windows Vista.  For example:

```
var isWindowsVista = function() {
  return (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") >= 0);
};
alert(isWindowsVista());
```

However, Windows 7 is called "Windows NT 6.1" so unless there are version numbers like 6.0.x.y then I doubt you can detect the Vista patch level in an "official" way.  Perhaps there are browser/DOM quirks that could let you infer patch level differences though.