# get specific windows version by javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-7, operating-system, windows-server-2008, user-agent

I do know I can get some Operation system information from "navigator.userAgent" on browser side using JavaScript, [and this post discus some details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006420/detect-windows-version-with-javascript)

My question is when I try to identify whether user is using windows 7 or windows server 2008 I get stuck. Because the windows version code are the same, they are both "windows NT 6.1".

Is there any other way to detect specific windows version on browser side using JavaScript except "navigator.userAgent"?

BTW, the following is my detection code. Currently I can not differentiate window 7 and windows server 2008...

```
(function (window) {
        //Windows detection
        var otherOS = "Other OS";
        var WindowsDetect = {
            Start: function () {
                this.OSVer = this.AnalyseOSVer(this.OSData) || otherOS;
                if (this.OSVer != otherOS) {
                    this.AnalyseBit();
                }
            },
            AnalyseOSVer: function (data) {
                var targetString = this.DataString.toUpperCase();
                if (targetString.indexOf(this.WinStr.toUpperCase() > 0)) {
                    this.IsWin = true;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var subString = data[i].SubString.toUpperCase();
                        if (typeof data[i].SpecialString != "undefined" && targetString.indexOf(data[i].SpecialString.toUpperCase()) < 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (targetString && targetString.indexOf(subString) > 0) {
                            return data[i].NickName;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            AnalyseBit: function () {
                var targetString = this.DataString.toUpperCase();
                for (var i = 0; i < this._64BitStrs.length; i++) {
                    var bitStr = this._64BitStrs[i].toUpperCase()
                    if (targetString.indexOf(bitStr) > 0) {
                        this.Is64Bit = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            },
            DataString: window.navigator.userAgent,
            _64BitStrs: ["WOW64", "Win64; x64;"],
            Is64Bit: false,
            WinStr: "Windows NT",
            IsWin: false,
            OSData: [
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 5.1",
                NickName: "Windows XP"
            },
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 5.2 ",
                NickName: "Windows Server 2003/Windows XP x64 Edition"
            },
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 6.0",
                NickName: "Windows Vista"
            },
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 6.1",
                NickName: "Windows 7"
            },
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 6.2",
                SpecialString: "ARM",
                NickName: "Windows RT"
            },
            {
                SubString: "Windows NT 6.2",
                NickName: "Windows 8"
            }
        ]
        };
        WindowsDetect.Start();
        var windowsVer = WindowsDetect.OSVer;
    })(window)
```

Comment: Can you post the different `window.navigator.userAgent`s you're being returned, for the 2 OS versions?

Comment: Hi @Cerbrus, I have a 64 bit windows server R2 the userAgent on IE9 is "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" and the userAgent on IE9 on windows 7 is "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"

Comment: So aside from the addition of `"WOW64"` in the userAgent on your Windows Server, there's no difference... The `"WOW64"` part has nothing to do with it being Windows Server, though... (It's a flag to show 64bit compatibility) 
So far for my good ideas.

Comment: @Cerbrus, the "WOW64" is indicate that I'm using 64 bit system... if I use 64 bit win7 there will also has a "WOW64". Plese see this blog http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx. I would like to know if there any other useful stuff JavaScript can use to do OS detection except userAgent string

Comment: Yea, I know. I'm not aware of any alternative options, I'm afraid...

Answer (score -1):

I was playing around with JavaScript and this worked the best.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2")!=-1) OSName="Windows 8";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1")!=-1) OSName="Windows 7";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0")!=-1) OSName="Windows Vista";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1")!=-1) OSName="Windows XP";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0")!=-1) OSName="Windows 2000";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="Mac/iOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

document.write('Your OS: '+OSName);
</script>
```

If you need some help, try this Wikipedia page on Windows NT. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases